# I Want to calculate grades in python but dont want to display grades if marks is less than 35 in any individual subject

Tags: python-3.x

I have done following code, but if student fails in one subject it still prints the grades  enter code here

```
sub1=int(input("Enter marks of the first subject: "))
sub2=int(input("Enter marks of the second subject: "))
sub3=int(input("Enter marks of the third subject: "))
sub4=int(input("Enter marks of the fourth subject: "))
sub5=int(input("Enter marks of the fifth subject: "))
avg=(sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub4)/5

if avg >= 60:
    print(avg)
    print('a')
elif avg >= 50 and avg < 60:
    print(avg)
    print('b')
elif avg >= 40 and avg < 50:
    print(avg)
    print('c')
elif avg >= 35 and avg < 40:
    print(avg)
    print('d')
elif sub1 or sub2 or sub3 or sub4 or sub5 < 35: #not sure about this
    print('na')
    print("you're failed")
```

Comment: i am writing program to print grades, but if a student has failed in one subject and passed in all other subject i want to print a message you,re failed in exam.

Comment: So to print the average result and also to print the failure message, if any one subject has failed?

Comment: printing you have failed. but not printing grades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
results = [sub1,  sub2,  sub3,  sub4,  sub5]
if any([res < 35 for res in results]):
    print('na')
    print("you've failed")
elif avg >= 60:
    print(avg)
    print('a')
elif avg >= 50:
    print(avg)
    print('b')
elif avg >= 40:
    print(avg)
    print('c')
elif avg < 40:
    print(avg)
    print('d')
```

**Explanation of the key line:**

`if any([res < 35 for res in results])` uses [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to loop through the results, checking if each item in `results` is less than 35.  The use of `any` means that if one or more of the results is less than 35, the condition is matched.  See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=any#any) for more about `any`.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. but i didnt understand 2nd line of code

Comment: Glad it helped.  I'll add an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your final `elif` statement isn't doing quite what you expect. For the `or` statements, you have to think of each bit of code between `or` statements as something that will return either True or False.

For example, in order to test whether either of two variables, a and b, are less than 5, you would want to do

```
if a < 5 or b < 5:
```

so you're testing whether either (a<5) is True, or (b<5) is True. If instead you had `if a or b < 5:` you'd actually be testing if (a) was True, or (b<5) was True, which isn't quite what you wanted to do.

So to apply that to your code, I think you should move that last statement to the top, and then have the other conditions nested within.

```
if any(np.array([sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5]) < 35):
    print('Unfortunately, you have failed.')
else:
    #If they have managed to get at least 35 in each of their assessments
    if avg >= 60: 
        Grade = 'A'
    elif avg < 60 and avg >= 50: 
        Grade = 'B'
    elif avg < 50 and avg >= 40: 
        Grade = 'C'

    print('Overall, average:', avg, ', grade:', Grade)
```

The `any()` statement is just a bit of a neater way of doing `if sub1<35 of sub2<35 ...` - the `np.array([sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4, sub5]) < 35` will return an array of True and False values, and the `any()` function will check if there are any True values in that array (i.e. if any of the grades are below 35).